# How do I make a section both scrollable and exactly as tall as the rest of the page?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a page with the following structure:

```
+-----------------------------------------+
|                 Header                  |
+----------+------------------------------+
| Sidebar  | Content                      |
|          |                              |
|          |                              |
|          |                              |
+----------+------------------------------+
```

I want the whole page to be exactly as tall as the viewport, i.e. `height: 100vh;`

The problem is that I want the Content section to be **as tall as needed** to fill the page, but to be **scrollable** at the same time (in case its children are too tall).

One easy solution would be to set the Content's height to `calc(100vh - height_of_header)` but this is sadly out of discussion because the header's height is not always constant.

I tried setting `height: -webkit-fill-available` on the Content section, but that didn't work (weirdly enough, it had the same effect as `height: 100%`)

I am considering using JS to solve this, but I would love to see a CSS-only solution.

I would prefer a solution that doesn't require `display: grid` but that's also fine! Thank you! :)

[Here is a codepen I made, in case it can be helpful](https://codepen.io/wil93/pen/WNxMYOe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `overflow-y: hidden` (although `auto` and `scroll` work as well) to the parent element (`<main>` in this case).

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised this worked, since `<main>` is the parent... And actually it works even if I set its `overflow-y` to `auto` or even `hidden`... It's just the default value (`visible`) which doesn't work. I'm still puzzled to why we need to set the overflow on the parent AND the child... But thanks a lot!